# how to understand what is the username and password of a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a problem in my connection string in c# that i don't remember what should we write instead of:
SERVERNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD in cs:

```
Data Source=SERVER NAME; Initial Catalog=DATABASE NAME; User ID=USERNAME; Password=PASSWORD
```

actually i made a data base with LeitnerBox name in sql server and i made some tables...
and at last i added a new user from security folder of my LeitnerBox folder, but i didn't give any password and i don't know what is my SERVERNAME?!!!?!!
so where can i find these information ???

->I use windows authentication when i log in to sql with IVS-PC server name!

Comment: User??? Did you mean `login`? The connection string should working with logins, not users. I know it can be confusing since the key name in the connection string to specify a login is called `User Id`.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ->I use windows authentication when i log in to sql with IVS-PC server name!
>
> i made a data base with LeitnerBox name in sql server

**1.** if you are running the `application` from same machine where `database` is located you can use either `.` or `localhost` for `server name` as they represent the current machine

**or**

if you know the `hostname` of `Database` server (machine where database is avaialble)you can provide your `hostname` aswell.

**2.** for `Database name` you can give `LeitnerBox` as you want to access it.

**3.** as you are using `windows authentication` to login into `sql server` you don't need to provide `User ID` and `Password`

**Note :** `User ID` and `Password` is required when you are using `SQL-Server Authentication` to Login.

**Method 1:** if you don't know the `hostname` of `database` located machine

```
  String ConnectionString ="Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=LeitnerBox;
      Integrated Security=True;"
```

**Method 2:** if you know the `hostname` of `database` located machine

```
  String ConnectionString ="Data Source=IVS-PC; Initial Catalog=LeitnerBox;
     Integrated Security=True;"
```

**4.** `User ID` and `Password` is required when you are using `SQL-Server Authentication` to Login.

User ID of SqlServer by default it will be `sa`
Password of Sql Server it is the password when you installed Sql-Server database.

**Method 3:** with `Sql-Server Authentication`

```
  String ConnectionString ="Data Source=IVS-PC; Initial Catalog=LeitnerBox;
     User ID=sa;Password=mypassword;Integrated Security=True;"
```

Comment: thank you very much
i got what should i do
but i remember before i used each database username and password to log in the sql and i used them in cs too!!!
so what should i do to connect i that way???

Comment: @user3125076: that time you might be logged in providing userid and password into sql server, you need to provide userid and password when you login with `SQL-Server Authenticaion`

Comment: @user3125076: see my detailed edit with 4th point, accpet one of the answer.

Comment: yes
and i know how to make a user for each database(in security folder of database add a user) but i don't know how to give a password for log in ???

Comment: @user3125076: you need to provide the password of the sql-server not the password of individual user.actually that is the password which you will provide while installing the sql server.

Comment: I got it!!!
and i remember what i'v done with your help!!!!!!
Thank you specially @Sudhakar (Y)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ConnectionString like

> "Server= localhost; Database= LeitnerBox; Integrated
>   Security=True;"

If you use Server Authentication in sql server then you need to use UserName and Password but for Windows Authentication , you don't need that